# Tomcat Manager: Specific JAVA_OPTS for each webapp

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, java-opts

On an Ubuntu Server 10.04 I have Tomcat6 installed. Additionally the Tomcat Manager is installed. Now there are 3 WAR-files containing different web applications.

When I upload any of these WAR-files via tomcat manager, it gets auto-deployed and starts up. But each webapp needs his own JAVA_OPTS like

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:NewRatio=2 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -DproductiveTomcat -DABC_KEY=/home/abc/tomcat/bin/abc.key -DABC_RESOURCES=/home/abc/tomcat/server/webapps -DRECOVERY_SCRIPT=/home/abc/e.sh
```

How can I tell Tomcat Manager to use these parameters for different web applications?

Comment: All the webapps will share the same VM so you cannot do that. You would need to run different instances of tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You could run three Tomcat instances bound to three different ports.